# Bootstrap-vue Collapse: show state with arrow

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I'm using Bootstrap-vue, and have a simple collapse component such that I can toggle the visibility of the content. I'm looking for a way to include an arrow icon in the toggle button that indicates the collapse state: arrow pointing down if content is opened, arrow pointing sideways if closed.

I have looked at the solution here [Bootstrap 4 Collapse show state with Font Awesome icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38970267/bootstrap-4-collapse-show-state-with-font-awesome-icon). However, while this works for Bootstrap 4, I can't make it work with Bootstrap-vue because the markup elements are different. So, given my markup below, how can I achieve the collapse state arrow?

```
<div>
  <b-btn v-b-toggle.collapse3 class="m-1">Toggle Collapse</b-btn>
  <b-collapse visible id="collapse3">
     <b-card> some content </b-card>
  </b-collapse>
</div>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This was my solution in the end, based on Riddhi's answer:

```
<b-btn block href="#" v-b-toggle.accordion1 variant="secondary">
   Time Period
     <span class="when-opened">
         <font-awesome-icon icon="chevron-down" />
     </span>
     <span class="when-closed">
         <font-awesome-icon icon="chevron-right" />
     </span>
</b-btn>

<b-collapse id="accordion1" role="tabpanel">
   <!-- some content -->
</b-collapse>
```

With additional CSS:

```
<style scoped>
...
    .collapsed > .when-opened,
    :not(.collapsed) > .when-closed {
        display: none;
    }

...
</style>
```

I installed and imported the Font Awesome packages, as described here https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/vuejs and https://origin.fontawesome.com/how-to-use/with-the-api/setup/importing-icons. The import code, in my main.js file, lookes like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
...
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { faChevronRight, faChevronDown } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'

library.add(faChevronRight, faChevronDown);

Vue.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon);
...
```

Answer (score 12):

Example HTML markup:

```
     <b-btn v-b-toggle.myCollapse>
          <span class="when-opened">
<i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
          <span class="when-closed">
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
          My Collapse
        </b-btn>
        <b-collapse id="myCollapse">
          <!-- content here -->
        </b-collapse>
```

Example Custom CSS:

```
.collapsed > .when-opened,
:not(.collapsed) > .when-closed {
  display: none;
}
```

You can achieve this with the help of above css classes.

Comment: Ok, this is great. Now, how do I include the icons "fa fa-chevron-down" and "fa fa-chevron-up", so that they actually show up?

Comment: Do I need to install the fontawesome library, as described here https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/vuejs, or is there a simpler way?

Comment: Yes you may go through this or can download the files (font-awesome-min.css) and put into your static assets and import them in your main.js file of the project.

Answer (score 2):

you can use a custom behavior when change the status with the event `this.$root.$on` check this doc:

> https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/collapse#collapse

> a simple example :)

```js
Vue.use(BootstrapVue);
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
      // collapsed has the status
      return { collapsed: false };
    },
    mounted() {
     // Emitted when collapse has
     // changed its state
     this.$root.$on(
      'bv::collapse::state',
      // id of the collapse component
      // collapse is the state
      // true => open, false => close
       (id, collapsed) => {
        if (id === "my-collapse") {
          this.collapsed = collapsed;
        }
      });// $on
    },
    // plus
    computed: {
      btnVariant: function () {
        return this.collapsed?
          'danger' : 'info'
      },
      btnTxt:  function () {
        return this.collapsed?
           ' Show ' : ' Hide';
      }
    }
});
```

```html
<!-- Required Stylesheets -->
<link
 type="text/css"
 rel="stylesheet"  href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
/>
<link
  type="text/css"
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.css"
/>

<!-- Required scripts -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>


<!-- markup template -->
<div id="app">
  <b-button
    v-b-toggle:my-collapse
    :variant="btnVariant">
    {{ btnTxt }} - Collapse
  </b-button>
  <b-collapse id="my-collapse">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
  </b-collapse>
</div>
```

good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

A more idiomatic approach would be to just use `v-model`, instead of using CSS to infer the UI state.

```html
<b-collapse visible id="collapse3">
  <b-card> some content </b-card>
</b-collapse>
```

should become:

```html
<b-collapse v-model="openState" id="collapse3">
  <b-card> some content </b-card>
</b-collapse>
```

You can decide to declare `openState` as `true` inside the data section or to set its value in the mounted or created lifecycle hooks, maybe based on a prop (as I did in my case). Once the user starts clicking, the value will be synchronized with its state in the UI.

The arrow part would then become:

```html
<span class="fa" :class="openState ? 'fa-chevron-down' : 'fa-chevron-up'"></span>
```

or

```
<font-awesome-icon :icon="openState ? 'chevron-down' : 'chevron-up'" />
```