# Bootstrap 4 Collapse state with Font Awesome icon

Tags: bootstrap-4, icons, font-awesome, bootstrap-table

I have a Bootstrap-table with Expand / Collapse but the start icon is not good.
The start icon when collapsed is "minus" and should be "plus", but if it's cliked 2 times, everything is OK.

I have used this example : [Bootstrap 4 Collapse show state with Font Awesome icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38970267/bootstrap-4-collapse-show-state-with-font-awesome-icon)

`my code :` https://jsfiddle.net/d7ycu6ne/

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS:

```css
[data-toggle="collapse"].collapsed .fa:before {
  content: "\f067"; /*plus*/
}
```

requires the row to have a class called "`collapsed`" in order to show the plus. But you haven't given it that class:

```html
<td data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#accordion1" 
    class="clickable" style="cursor:pointer">
```

If you use your browser's dev tools to look at the DOM, you will see that the Bootstrap library is adding that "`collapsed`" class whenever you click the minus to collapse (beginning with the second click).

So of course you should start the element with that class already applied:

```html
<td data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#accordion1"
    class="clickable collapsed" style="cursor:pointer">
```